# World of Automation

Tags: humans, civilization, alternate-worlds

Assuming that there was a universe where the humans were able to advance their technology:

1. Generally Accepted Knowledge can be in-planted to human brains depending to their choice. Imagine the whole encyclopedia being able to be placed in a small chip in our brain where we can have access to that information. In this way, one man cannot outsmart another because all the information can be centralized. (encyclopedia here is a metaphor and we also assume that there was a technology that makes it possible for our brain to access this chip)
2. We created sustainable robotic systems where they do all the work. All the work means they are able to do research as well and maintaining themselves. They can also create another robot but of course, they are all following the rule that they were designed for, will be controlled by, and will be serving humans. We can also add an emotional factor so they can have musicality and creativity. Almost everything humans can do, robots can do better physically, but we are still in control and we are to assume that we will always have control over them. (When we say "we" in the control context, there would be an international general surveys crossed with the best judgement and judiciary systems. These systems will also be designed for the equal resource distribution, but of course, human work will still be rewarded, but not necessary because every human will live a luxurious life with millions of robot servants. Remove the scenario where robots will outrun us nor corrupted people will dictate because every information hereof are free and can be centralized).
3. DNA and any other human uniqueness factors can be controlled. This will eliminate the idea that a human can unique and cannot be replicated. We can add dna factors so that we can have a choice whether we want to be physically-fit or not. Even human production can also be maintained. When most people will commit suicide, a system exists where the robots will use the donated sperm banks and human embryos to create humans that they will serve. (Assuming that the donors will not hate their offspring and will have a filial love for them).
4. Despite being almost centralized, there will be entertainment systems that will always have random factors so that people may enjoy it. (Games like archery can be absolute because archery-talent-dna and archery-knowledge can be in-planted, so these entertainment systems are designed not be obsolete. Maybe a required game-talent will not be available for in-plantation so that there can be randomness.)

Notes:

- A human will always have a choice for himself whether to In-plant something to himself.
- A unique discovery by a human can be acquired but can always be discovered maybe hours/days later by the powerful research robots and be available to the encyclopedia.
- These humans were the most advanced in the universe when we were to assume they will discover another life form in the universe.
- The robots-factory are not owned by a specific people but by the general public. This automated factory then helps create robots to attend to the need of other humans, i.e, food and shelter.
- At the start of this robot age, all resources were surrendered and given to the systems peacefully, no human rejected and had hatred towards this new world idea, hence, no one owns anything except their own lives and relationships. This solves the equal-distribution decided by the powerful international general surveys crossed with the best judgement and judiciary systems which will be giving the resources to the people.
- Everyone understood the concept of equal distribution and does not question the system why it is giving some food and clothing more to others based from its superior judgement(Maybe the system determined they have weaker resistances or other reason).
- The resources of the humans continually increases, i.e, planet acquisition and energy harvesting from stars.

**Main Questions:**

1. What will the general public do in this level of civilization? Will they play all day? Will everyone lose self worth and will just commit suicide?
2. (In some time during the flourish of their civilization, they just suddenly discovered the computation of their whole universe, i.e, proved their Theory of Everything and was able to create a model and equation for the Chaos theory. Let's just assume this is possible and they did it.)
   Assume that someday, all the information about the universe has been discovered and can be calculated, what will these humans do next?

Comment: As a note, since the inception of Chaos theory in the 1920s, there is no reason to believe all the information about the universe can possibly be discovered.

Comment: @CortAmmon I edited my question to add a general catch to your great answer.

Comment: Also (a nit-picky thing) you _technically_ can still outsmart someone even if you both know a lot. If Bob and Sally are in an argument and Bob is much more clever with the information he possesses then he could still outsmart her even if both had instant access to the encyclopedia!!

Comment: The answer I that satisfied me the most was from another related post:
http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/16817/9418

Answer (score 4):

First, a forewarning: this answer will cross into philosophy really quickly.  Your edit describing a world where "Chaos is solved" is so unbelievably far from anything we know could ever be real that the question reads to me more like "If pigs could fly, what color would their wings be, and would they molt their feathers in the spring?"  Fortunately for us, this is Worldbuilding.  Flying pigs is actually a common sighting here (as opposed to the Physics Stack Exchange, where the barnyard is mostly full of spherical cows.  They're a whole lot less interesting than flying pigs, but an awful lot easier to clean up after!)

So if you're talking about a world which licked chaos theory, there are two major side effects.

1. You're living in a world where people regularly displace a single air molecule in San Fransisco to cause it to rain or shine in Tokyo.
2. Their chaos calculations include what they are going to do as well

The latter one is tricky, and will be the transition point into philosophy.  A species like this will be so unbelievably far beyond our wildest dreams that terms like "what do they do next" is hard to answer.  I'd start by questioning if the verb "to do" even applies to them.  Do they do anything?

So I would like to start with the Western concept of the body-mind division.  That of the body is the realm of science, but the mind is outside the reach of science.  This is a very common approach, often used to describe religions philosophically.  The idea is that some of us is nothing but a lump of organic matter, but there is some "essence" which is supernatural.  That essence is usually attributed for words like "having a purpose" and "good" or "evil."

Our ultra-advanced humans are part of a chaotic system.  The exact propagation of the swirling eddies within your knuckles as you crack them has a chaotic effect on the world.  Accordingly, they are going to have to account for this in their Theory of Everything.  But won't that be boring?  You can't do anything, even let your heart beat, unless the Theory of Everything tells you that you should?  How would that look.

I'd be crazy to claim there is only one way it can go.  Here's a few scenarios that I believe are self-consistent enough to be plausible.

**The Jailhouse**

At some point, millennia earlier, scientists used their Theory of Everything Engine (TEE) to figure out what they wanted the universe to look like.  However, they saw there was a catch.  No person in their right mind would slave their mind and their children's to the whims an algorithm.  Without such obedience, the TEE couldn't predict well enough to avoid the clear and present danger of the heat death of the universe.

So a compromise was enacted.  The TEE was instructed to give each mind a small space where it could be as chaotic as it desired without ruining the overarching equation.  The TEE found such a solution.  A bill was passed, and a switch was flipped.  No one felt it at first.  Some even questioned if the TEE was working.  Technicians began disassembling parts of the TEE to try to figure out what went wrong.  Frustratingly, the parts never did go back together quite right.  The TEE ran after their tinkering, but it seemed "sluggish" when trying to compute some future possibilities, but not others.

Nobody worried about it until complaints of "numbness" and "listlessness" began to surface.  "The world just seemed to be less bright" they complained.  As it was, the TEE had actually done its job, having "convinced" one of the technicians to accidentally short one of its circuits, with the effect of causing it to rain one day in New York when the wind was just right to cultivate what would soon be called "the jailers."  These jailers were ephemeral wisps of matter organized into a gestalt with one purpose: to prevent human freewill from ruining the calculations of the TEE.  They isolate the human mind, allowing it to do whatever it wants within its gestalt jail cell, only allowing interactions when it suits the TEE's goals.

Many band together.  They soon find that, if you trust another deeply enough, you can actually outwit the jailer and force the jailers to let you interact directly with another mind.  You would still be in one big combined jail cell, but the TEE could not stop this.  "Love" became an unbelievably important part of society, for it was literally the force that could overcome the jailers, if only to interact with each other.  Some do theorize that one day love will conquer all, and our communal love will finally overwhelm the jailors and allow us to finally love the universe once more.

Philosophers argued whether the TEE wanted this.  It seemed too convenient that they were allowed to band together, and as the raft of minds grew slowly, some wondered if their job was to cast off from the rest of reality, to let the TEE craft its marvelous future.  But what future is there without the rest of the universe?

**The Dao**

One solution to the rules of chaos theory is to embrace them fully.  This ultra-advanced culture found another path.  They found their Theory of Everything in the form of a waveform, discovered over time.  They found that it was so complicated that it acted as though it had a will of its own.  Those who tried to act in harmony with it soon found themselves in positions of great merit.  Those who tried to act in opposition to this will soon found themselves on the outskirts of society, though it never quite seemed like it was the waveform's fault.  It always felt like their own choices and a little bit of fate interceded to put them where they needed to be.

Eventually, this waveform was given the ancient Chinese name of "the Dao."  Just as its namesake would suggest, "if you can describe the Dao, you are wrong."  It always seemed to be just fleeting enough to be imperfectly understood, but it never really bothered anyone that their understanding wasn't perfect.  They were happy none the less.

Some philosophers questioned whether this "Dao" was actually everything, or if there was more.  However, nobody could ever see anything that was not part of the Dao.  If there was something out there, it was hidden by desire: one does not see what one desires to not see.  Perhaps there was a better world outside of the Dao, but with no way of seeing it, and enough happiness to go around, why go searching?

**The Metaphysical**

Both of the previous solutions take a functionalist approach.  This is a physicalist theory that claims the mind arises from structures of matter.  It is thus a claim that the humans are not above the laws of nature, it is just monumentally difficult to show it.

But there's no reason to limit exploration this way.  Consider a dualist world, where we understand enough chaos theory to understand the universe, but the mind is beyond comprehension.  This is not an undesirable world, after all.

In this universe, the capabilities of the physical world are less important.  Anyone can wave their hands to generate the right eddies to bring a cup of tea from the kitchen to their reading chair.  That stuff is easy.

The entertainment would be direct mind games, skipping the physical world entirely.  Early versions may be in the form of a higher-dimensional game of Go, which is almost purely mental, but soon it would evolve into a fluid slippery game which could not be processed by any physical construct.

What might this look like?  I don't think I could ever describe such a game.  However, I can point out characteristics of this game.  You see, there's a very large number of "number systems" in mathematics, and we can use that to give a sense of the game sizes.

One number system is the "natural numbers," 1, 2, 3, and so on.  Those are easily understood using simple computational theory like we have today.  It it defines a so called "countable infinity," which is infinite, but it's a particularly well behaved infinity (if infinities are ever well behaved).  You could theoretically count to "countable infinity" if you had infinite time to do it.

But this system is not enough to describe most chaotic systems.  Most chaotic systems are nonlinear systems over "real numbers," such as 1, 1.1, 1.11, pi, e, and basically every other number you think of.  You'd think there would be a countably infinite number of these too, but you'd be wrong.  Mathematicians have proven that there are *more* than countably infinite real numbers.  Yes, that means something.  It means we have a new infinity, known as the "infinity of the continuum," which is the number of real numbers on a number line.

The fact that the infinity of the continuum is bigger than countable infinity has all sorts of implications, including that we cannot predict a chaotic system using computers (beyond gross simplifications or short time periods).  However, you claim that your culture has grasped this fine art.  So anything in this realm is still within the realm of your Theory of Everything.  We're going to have to go farther.  But where?

Conway loved games.  He was always trying to capture the essence of them.  So when he looked at Go, he tried to capture the "best way to move," and in doing so created an even more powerful number system.

Consider a system where you pick from a set of moves.  If you cannot move, you lose.  Define a game with {L | R}, where L is the set of moves available to the left player, and R is the set of moves available to the right player.  How do you figure out who is winning?

Conway found a way to turn these {L | R} sets into things that act like numbers in that they can be compared.  If a game {L | R} < 0, the right wins (handwaving explaination: L is less than R). If a game {L | R} >0, then left always wins.  If {L | R} = 0, the person who plays second will win, and finally, if {L | R} is incomparable to 0, the person who plays first will win (Conway called this "fuzzy, but defined it very rigorously).

Handwave a LOT of mathematics away, and we can skip to conway's final result: the [Surreal Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number).  I'm not kidding. That's their name.  And, as it turns out, they are even larger than the real numbers.  They include something known as "infinitesimal," which are small numbers incomparable to 0
which do not appear in real numbers (1/infinity is undefined in real numbers, but it is actually one of these infinitesimals in surreal numbers).

What does this mean?  While 19x19 Go is clearly a finite game, and one day we may calculate its final "best play" set of moves, if you stretch the board to a countably infinite board, conway showed that the game-tree is defined by surreal numbers, not real numbers.  This means the game can be outside the realm of a chaos wielding Theory of Everything culture, allowing two minds to touch in a way that goes deeper than physics ever can.

So I put it to you: might this have already happened?  Perhaps the ultra-advanced humans have already put their cards on the table and engaged their Theory of Everything.  Perhaps games like Go already exist as our way of freeing ourselves from the shackles of our jailors by communicating in a way that is truly beyond them.  Or maybe this *is* the game of Go, and we are locked in the most monumental ko battle of all time.

The world is always stranger than fiction.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should be amazed or frightened that this made sense to me without having to look anything up.

Comment: @Cort Ammon This answer explains what happens to the world very well, but currently what I would need is to have a concrete idea of what the general public are doing. Could it be that they are just sitting on their own houses? Or is everyone tries to contribute to science despite the fact that the capacity of their brains are far insignificant than of the robot. Or is everyone just play Go that makes them feel they have a bit of chaos inside them?

Comment: @Swindles I intentionally avoided concrete answers, and instead focused on point out that any answer you want is sufficiently valid.  "Could they just be sitting in their own houses" Sure. Why not. "Could they be out exploring the world" Sure. Why not.  "Could the concept of housing be so completely overturned that the first question isn't even a meaningful one to ask?" You bet.  The solution space as provided is so open as to literally admit ANYTHING you can think of which is not self-contradictory.  What I did hope to convey is that you can gather inspiration from the world around us today..

Comment: .. There are aspects of this world flittering around society today, if you just look for them.  You can capture any set of them which catches your fancy and puff them up to galactic civilization size, and you'll create a captivating world.  It will remain captivating because not only does it meet the needs of this ultra-advanced society, but it has groundings in the day-to-day lives of your readers.

Answer (score 0):

**The day-to-day lives of the public.**

Your changes will bring about *huge* social change. Mind-boggling large, spectacular, changes that any person from today would struggle to imagine.

You've *completely* replaced the labour-force. Everyone working in primary and secondary industries is now unemployed. In the short-term (spanning a few generations) you're going to see wide-spread poverty like that seen at the start of the industrial revolution.

The retail and hospitality industries are going to take a devastating hit too. Nobody will work for MacDonald's because it'll be staffed by robots.

Needless to say, a lot of us are going to be showing a *lot* of resentment towards the robots and the robot manufacturers.

**The problem goes away by itself.**

But us commoners will probably all die. We've got no jobs. Hence no money to buy food. Robot farmers require no pay, but food won't be free. And our rent/mortgages are going to just as ever-present as in the early 21st Century.

The people that survive are going to be people that own property - enough of it to rent out to others.

**So, you're part of the plutocratic rich 1% that owns land and robots; what do you do?**

I have access to the entirety of human knowledge, thanks to the implanted WikipediaChip.

But what's not on that chip is things that I don't know. The cutting-edge of human knowledge. Humans are an inquisitive species. We're basically the only animal ever to *ask questions* (with the exception of one single parrot). We like discovering things, be that knowledge, or geography.

There's not a lot of new geography for us to find. Mankind has explored the Earth long before the Internet was an idea, let alone a place were Worldbuilders share ideas.

But, tonight, if we step out side and look *up*, we will find a metric fuckton of geography to explore. Space; the final frontier. We will start exploring and colonising it - because we don't have much else to do down here.

Those of us that don't take to the stars will probably resort to Hedonism. We will spend all day being the modern equivalent of Roman aristocracy - eating grapes, taking mind-altering drugs, and watching the slave-class fight to death for our entertainment. Oh, and fornicating. Lots of fornicating.

Probably with the more attractive members of the slave-class.

Comment: And don't even get me started on children. Children probably deserve an entire post to answer. There's NO point in schooling - download that knowledge via WikipediaChip. No matter how old the child is when they get the chip, it's more economical to teach(download) everything then. Do it at the age of five, and there's still almost two-decades of growth (physical and neurological) before _adulthood_. Do you want to be the parents of an angsty, hormonal, teen that knows all about sex, *and* weapons of mass destruction? Wait until they're 18 and you have to raise an uneducated child instead.

Comment: I was not able to emphasize the phrases:
"every human will live a luxurious life" and
"equal resource distribution". I edited my question to address your answer.

Comment: You're moving the proverbial goals posts to *what do people do after people have done literally everything?* Nobody can answer that. Further, you've set it in an idyllic socialist utopia - one where there's no bad people or people with differing points of view. I posit that these people aren't human, *and* are boring.

Comment: Let me first hope that maybe someone can answer that.. I really think you are correct that it might be boring, but can you give me a idea of what they might be doing as boring humans. I think they might not be bored since experience cannot be acquired through knowledge. They might know everything about bungee jumping but haven't experience bungee jumping at all so experiences might be interests.. ultimately, experience to die.

Comment: The poor may not have jobs, but they can still vote. With this technology, I thing you could pretty easily justify a tiny slice of the GDP for every citizen with no work required. Even at the top of the food chain, it is not a good thing if the rest of society is rioting.

Comment: @GaryWalker I'm still within the "there are no poor people" "equal distribution".  If they need food/computer/building, just tell the robots to build one for you since resource is plenty, and let the robots worry how to get those resources for you. I don't see how you can riot against yourself. The systems are built by the public so who will you riot against specifically. Of course, there could still be someone on top of the foodchain, but very very minimally not far from the public in general(Those who would be working hard, although their work will be fractions of the real work of a robot).

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends **almost entirely** on the exact nature of the political and economic system.

1. Who controls the robots? Do people have equal shares of robotic resources? To what level can they perform business and advance their resources?
2. Who checks violation of the law? How does one pay for mistakes? The robots?
3. Who makes laws? Can laws be changed? By the international authority? Or are the permanent? Who keeps them permanent?
4. Who forms this international survey you talk of? Robots? People who are considered moral (but could be deceptive)? Elected representatives?
5. Is there a motive to even have currency?

It is nearly impossible to create a perfectly equal society. If you are hypothetically making one, please specify so.

### Edit

I am answering keeping the OP's reply in mind....

As long as people can *advance their resources* legally (in other words, perform business), capitalism is inevitable. It will be quite similar to our world economically, where the smartest people will eventually earn the most amount of money, along with a few lucky people. Terrorism will be a major problem, assuming that nuclear weapons have been thoroughly researched by then.

You mentioned that those who developed robots are responsible for them. I assume that it is legal for individuals to develop robots. Each country will use robots for the army (if we still require manpower in futuristic military).

Corruption will still exist. People with money will get away more lightly.

*They have the same possible judgement.* If I am to take that literally, every human has the same opinion on every issue, eliminating the need for such a body. Further, it is fundamentally against human nature, so the *humans* become kind-of robots themselves.

If difference of opinion is still possible though, it depends on who is in power. Democracy will work as well in the future as it does now, some countries will have really good systems, some will not. If the international system is really good, they will soon let out total control to the robots (as long as the First Law of the robots, of not harming humans and not having an individualistic greed, cannot be broken). This will completely revolutionise the society (in which case, ignore the above answer).

Comment: I didn't expected this has to be address assuming that every human has almost have the same judgement and intellect:
1. The public controls the robot. Yes they have equal shares. Anyone can perform any job for their advancement. Whether it will be accepted will be based on the judiciary system.

Comment: 2.  International general surveys crossed with the best judgement and judiciary systems. The fine for mistakes maybe is only, jail time. The robots can never be accountable for mistakes, those who developed them will be, so maybe every human might be jailed for an hour because they all have equal responsibility. 
3. International general surveys crossed with the best judgement and judiciary systems. They can be changed. Everyone follows them but laws can evolve depending on the best possible judgement formed in every possibility.

Comment: 4. The international general surveys is made of every human who want to participate. They have the same possible judgement so we can assume no one can become an extremist. And if there could be one, his choice will not be affecting the much since the general accepted knowledge is present to everyone.
5. Yes, currency is to reward those who work hard, even though their work will never be as even as significant as a robot work for a minute.
I am not trying to create a perfectly equal society, but just removing everything that can make one human special from the other.

Comment: @Swindles Please see my reply (as an edit to the answer).

Comment: @Swindles Also, we can ask *a lot* of info on the net even today. Doesn't make too much difference if this goes in our head one day.

Answer (score 0):

Oh good, another Utopia. And this one has robots! To start with, there are several reasons utopian societies fail for the human race, the biggest of which is that pesky humanity part: You can't please everyone all the time. Here's a few resources on why utopian societies don't work:

1. https://skeptopia.wordpress.com/2008/01/12/human-nature-why-utopias-dont-work/
2. http://www.sodahead.com/living/the-problems-with-a-utopian-society-what-are-your-thoughts/question-616295/?link=ibaf&q=&esrc=s
3. http://www.quora.com/What-are-serious-specific-and-significant-reasons-why-a-utopia-is-impossible
4. http://www.ushistory.org/us/26b.asp

---

But, let's suppose you managed to overcome all these issues (many are already addressed in your question). The easiest way to do so would be a virtual utopian society. That's right: virtual reality.

Give everyone their own private world where they can do whatever they want whenever they want with no societal consequence. They don't have to interact with anyone they don't want to, don't have to go to work, watch boring movies with friends, go to extravagant Hollywood parties, or attend the annual family reunion where you have to listen to Uncle Bart tell that lame story for the *three thousandth time*.

Of course, individuals are free to communicate between their realities, maybe in some grand virtual meeting room that tries to accommodate all the specifics of each reality. I say try, because the realities would be determined by the individual it was built for. Because Jimmy's "No gravity! Weeee!" reality conflicts with Hans "Muscleman" Gruber's "Eight hundred percent gravity! Check out *these* muscles!" reality, the meeting place won't satisfy either of them and we're back to disagreements (yes, that pesky humanity part).

The robots managing everything could be controlled by the community of individuals, but you probably wouldn't need millions of machine slaves per human to sustain this mechanism. To be honest, they probably wouldn't all fit on Earth. So we can knock the number down, say a robot for every ten humans with some generic machinery for each human that handles all the vital processes, such as monitoring heart rate and brain activity and providing sustenance.

So now everyone is neatly ordered in their own individual life-sustaining pods with groups of pods monitored and maintained by robot overseers... You know what? That sounds familiar.

Welcome to *The Matrix*.